# Reading static files on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I'm on a solution with multiple projects, and I'm having issues accessing a project outside the one I'm currently on. Here's a very simplified structure of my codebase:

```
-ProjectA
     -Pages
          Index.razor
-ProjectB
    - Images
          -image.jpg
```

I'm on ProjectA using Blazor Server and I need to read an image outside my directory in ProjectB. I created a static file using the following code:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
             Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"./../ProjectB/Images/")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/MyImages")
        });
```

The thing is, when I use "/MyImages" inside of an html img tag followed with the filename, it works fine and I can view any image in ProjectB. However, this does not work when I'm using System.IO code such as:

```
@code{
File.ReadAllBytes("/MyImages/image.jpg");
}
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I should have been a bit more clearer on the purpose of my project.

I have three classes that I'm dealing with, `Product`, `CreateProduct` and `EditProduct`. Those classes have the same properties like `Name, Price, etc`. The only difference is that `Product` has the string `ImagePath` while `CreateProduct` and `EditProduct` have `IFormFile Image`.

When I want to create a new Product, I read the string values like name, price, etc, then for the image, I use `InputFile` which gives me a `IBrowserFile`, do some basic conversion process to an `IFormFile` then POST it as a `CreateProduct`. In the backend, the API will store the IFormFile in the file system (aka ProjectB) then create a `Product` record in the DB which has the ImagePath.

Here's the snippet of code for this process:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> PostProduct([FromForm] CreateProduct model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();
            // This function helpers.UploadFiles will just write the file to the file system, then return the url
           // For example, it'll return "/product_1/image.jpg"
            var ProductImagePath = await _helpers.UploadFiles(model.Image);

            var product = new Product
            {
                //news
                Name = model.Name,
                Price = model.Price,
                ImagePath = ProductImagePath,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            _context.Product.Add(Product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And this is how it looks on the frontend:

```
// Converting my IBrwserFile(imageFile) to bytes so that it can be posted as IForm (Probably could do it better but that's an issue for another day)
using Stream filestream = imageFile.OpenReadStream(1024 * 1024 * 15);
using MemoryStream ms = new();
await filestream.CopyToAsync(ms);
byte[] productImage = ms.ToArray();


var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
         {new StringContent("SomeProductName"),"Name"},
         {new StringContent("SomeProductPrice"),"Price" },
         {
            new ByteArrayContent(productImage), "Image", fileName
         },
    };
                await client.PostAsync("Product/", formContent);
```

My PUT request follows the same structure. The tricky part is the `EditProduct` scenario. I first have to do a GET request and receive the `Product` instance which only has the image path. There are two scenarios that editing my product entails:

Scenario 1:

```
1- Make a GET request for the `Product` class which has the image path
2- View all information including the image on the browser using <img src="ImagePath">
3- Decide to use a different image, which then I just call InputFile
4- Process InputFile and convert it to IFormFile
5- Make a PUT request and post the updated information to `EditForm` class
```

This works out fine. However in Scenario 2:

```
1- Steps 1 & 2 as before
2- Decide not to change the image, but change other stuff like the Name and price
3- ????
```

Now I need to make a PUT request but since I didn't use InputFile, I don't have an IFormFile that I can send to the PUT request for `EditForm` class.
In order for the PUT process to work properly, I need to read the image I got from the ImagePath using `File.ReadAllBytes` then read it to memory and convert it to an `IFormFile`.

As I mentioned at the start I can view the image using `<img src="/MyImages/@imagePath />`, with `/MyImages` being the static file path I created on Startup.cs. That doesn't work when I apply it to `File.ReadAllBytes` or any other IO functions.

Comment: Show us the code that *doesn't* work.

Comment: Sorry I should have highlighted it, when I use `<img src="/MyImages/image.jpg">` it works fine but when I write something like `File.ReadAllBytes("/MyImages/image.jpg");` It doesn't work. I've tried variations of that code such as adding a $ to the start of the path or a ~ but to no avail.

Comment: If you are already "in" the MyImages folder, try `File.ReadAllBytes("./MyImages/image.jpg");`   Otherwise, it's going to be something along the lines of `File.ReadAllBytes("/ProjectB/MyImages/image.jpg");`  It's a path problem, in other words.

Comment: Also, where is `MyImages` in your very simplified structure?

Comment: My tip as a programmer-- avoid telling people what your program *doesn't* do. If it "doesn't work," say what it *does instead*, e.g. "it throws an exception (and the specific exception is ____)." The point is to compare expected and actual behaviors. You will save a lot of time if you do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @JohnWu, I'll do my best not to make that mistake again. And Robert, the `MyImages` is just the shortcut for the folder in ProjectB. When I write `<img src="/MyImages/image.jpg">`, that is mapped to `<img src="/ProjectB/Images/image.jpg">`  but when I use `File.ReadAllBytes("/MyImages/image.jpg");`, it is mapped to `File.ReadAllBytes("/ProjectA/MyImages/image.jpg");`, meaning it is not properly converting the path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your two projects are compiled under different folder systems, but are hosted under the same domain (say, "localhost/A" and "localhost/B").  From your browser's point of view, there's no problem.

But if you are trying to access files in your physical system, there's a problem because they have different root paths, and aren't actually sharing any folders.  (which is as it should be, since you don't want 2 apps struggling for control over the file system)

Why do you want direct access to the image files?  Will you manipulate them from your other project somehow?

Comment: Thanks I didn't think of it that way. I edited my question to add some more context.